# Subtract and intercalate lists

Tags: list-manipulation

I have a list where the sum of its values results 10:

```
timeEachStep = {{0.7646050049957724}, {1.1043813977215065}, {1.792518103577381}, {1.5769143982179603}, {2.475716623701331}, {2.2858644717860503}}  
Plus @@ timeEachStep
```

> $\left(
> \begin{array}{c}
>  0.764605 \\
>  1.10438 \\
>  1.79252 \\
>  1.57691 \\
>  2.47572 \\
>  2.28586 \\
> \end{array}
> \right)$
>
> ${10}$

And I have another value that will change the above list

```
tClaw = 0.2
```

> $0.2$

With my limited knowledge I had to create a list of work

```
list2 = Table[tClaw, Length[timeEachStep]]
```

> $\{0.2,0.2,0.2,0.2,0.2,0.2\}$

This list should be added to the other list, but without changing the sum of values. Then I did a subtraction, then I added the values intercalating.

```
list3 = timeEachStep - list2  
Plus @@ list3
```

> $\left(
> \begin{array}{c}
>  0.564605 \\
>  0.904381 \\
>  1.59252 \\
>  1.37691 \\
>  2.27572 \\
>  2.08586 \\
> \end{array}
> \right)$
>
> ${8.8}$

```
newList = Flatten[Transpose[{list3, list2}]]  
Plus @@ newList
```

> $\{0.564605,0.2,0.904381,0.2,1.59252,0.2,1.37691,0.2,2.27572,0.2,2.08586,0.2\}$
>
> $10$

There is a specific function that makes this?

Comment: `Flatten@Riffle[timeEachStep - tClaw, tClaw, {2, -1, 2}]` should do it.

Comment: Yes. It's that simple.

Comment: `Flatten@{# - tClaw, tClaw} & /@ timeEachStep`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As has already been mentioned by [Marius Ladegård Meyer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/128143/subtract-and-intercalate-lists#comment346624_128143)

```
Flatten@Riffle[timeEachStep - tClaw, tClaw, {2, -1, 2}]
```

Yields:

> $\{0.564605,0.2,0.904381,0.2,1.59252,0.2,1.37691,0.2,2.27572,0.2,2.08586,0.2\}$